# SQL to find timespan between rows based on ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table in a SQL db (HeartbeatHistory)

```
Timestamp | Comment | Id
------------------------
```

The comment can contain OK or ERR

The Id is the Id of the thing that has that comment.

I want to be able to query the table and find the durations that any given id was in an Error state.

```
Timestamp | Comment | Id
------------------------
12:00:00  | OK      | 1
11:59:00  | ERR     | 2
11:58:00  | OK      | 4
11:57:00  | OK      | 3
11:45:00  | ERR     | 4
11:20:00  | OK      | 2
11:00:00  | ERR     | 3
11:30:00  | OK      | 5
11:20:00  | ERR     | 1
11:10:00  | OK      | 1
11:00:00  | ERR     | 1
10:30:00  | ERR     | 5
```

So in the above table If I queried for 11:00:00 to 13:00:00 I would want to see.

```
ErrorStart | ErrorEnd | Id
--------------------------
11:00:00   | 11:10:00 | 1
11:20:00   | 12:00:00 | 1
11:59:00   | 12:00:00 | 2
11:00:00   | 11:57:00 | 3
11:45:00   | 11:58:00 | 4
11:00:00   | 11:30:00 | 5
```

(notice 5 started error before query date!!)

Is this possible? Also an Id might change state multiple times during the queried period.

So far I have this, which works for a single Id, but I need to make it work for multiple Ids.

```
declare @startDate datetime = @from;
declare @endDate datetime = @to;
declare @kpiId = 1;

select Foo.RowCreatedTimestamp, Foo.Comment, Foo.NextTimeStamp, Foo.NextComment, Foo.HeartBeatId, Foo.NextHeartBeatId
from (
    select RowCreatedTimestamp, Comment,
    lag(RowCreatedTimestamp, 1, 0) over (order by RowCreatedTimestamp desc) as NextTimeStamp, 
    lag(Comment, 1, 0) over (order by RowCreatedTimestamp desc) as NextComment,
    HeartBeatId
    from dbo.tblHeartbeatHistory
    where RowCreatedTimestamp >= @startDate and RowCreatedTimestamp <= @endDate
    and HeartbeatId in
        (
            select HeartbeatId
            from dbo.tblKpiHeartBeats
            where KpiId = @kpiId
        )                       
) as Foo
where Foo.Comment like '%set to ERR%'
order by Foo.RowCreatedTimestamp desc;
```

So if the select `HeartbeatId from dbo.tblKpiHeartBeats` returns a single Id, this works. As soon as their are multiple id's it does not :(

To avoid confusion:

The table with the Timestamp, Comment and Id is HeartbeatHistory.

The other table referenced in my SQL is dbo.tblKpiHeartBeats.

This table looks like:

```
Kpi | HeartbeatId
-----------------
1   | 1
1   | 2
1   | 3
1   | 4
1   | 5
```

So i want all the error intervals for Kpi = 1, it would return the error intervals for HeartbeatId 1,2,3,4 and 5.

Further note. The data may have multiple errors in a row before an OK comes in.

It may just be all ERR for the query period or all OK.

Comment: Your question states that you have one table, but your query references multiple tables.  That makes is really hard to understand what is going on.

Comment: Hi, I've udpated the question. You're right that was a bit confusing. Basically I want to query the HeartbeatHistory table which has the TImestamp, Comment and heartbeatId and find all the error periods for each heartbeatId that is in the KPIHeartbeatId (I will pass the KPIId)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add second CTE Id you want full join ERR AND OK rows (Code below only for OK rows)

```
WIRH History AS (
    SELECT 
    FROM HeartbeatHistory  
    WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd
), Errors AS(
    SELECT Id, MIN(Timestamp) AS ErrorStart 
    FROM History 
    WHERE Comment = 'ERR'
    GROUP BY Id
)
SELECT 
    ErrorStart = E.ErrorStart ,  
    ErrorEnd   = O.Timestamp,
    Id         = O.Id
FROM History           O
LEFT JOIN Errors       E ON E.Id = O.Id
WHERE O.Comment = 'OK'
```

Edit: You can add prevOK timespan (or PK) column to the table (probably computed persistent) - link to last good row. It will be used as Id of row in your report.

Try this index:

`CREATE INDEX IDX_EXAMPLE ON HeartbeatHistory (Timestamp, Id, prevOK, Comment)`

```
WIRH History AS (
    SELECT 
    FROM HeartbeatHistory  
    WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd
)
SELECT 
    ErrorStart = E.ErrorStart ,  
    ErrorEnd   = O.Timestamp,
    Id         = O.Id
FROM History           O
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MIN(Timestamp) AS ErrorStart 
    FROM History  E
    WHERE E.Id = O.ID AND E.prevOK = O.prevOK 
)
WHERE O.Comment = 'OK'
```

Comment: I modified this to run and it's incredibly slow. It's been running for 2 minutes without finishing. The table heartbeatHistory has around 35 million rows.

Comment: Have you any indexes on this table?

Comment: Yes, there are indexes on Timestamp desc, a PK on HeartbeatHistoryId (I don't need but can't change the PK) and Id Ascending.

Comment: @Stuart I've edited my answer to provide better result

Comment: I made a slight change to get it to work, but it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use `lead()`.  If I assume that `ERR` does not occur twice in a row (as in your sample data):

```
select (case when timestamp >= '11:00:00' then timestamp else '11:00:00' end) as errorStart,
       (case when next_timestamp <= '13:00:00' then next_timestamp else '13:00:00') as errorEnd,
       id
from (select t.*,
             lead(timestamp) over (partition by id order by timestamp) as next_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
where comment = 'ERR' and
      (timestamp <= '13:00:00' and
       (next_timestamp >= '11:00:00' or next_timestamp is null)
      );
```

Comment: There may be a whole lot of errors in a row. Then an OK. This is information that comes in every x minutes for each Id reporting it's status. It might say ERR, ERR, ERR, OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @table      TABLE (Timestmp TIME(1), Comment NVARCHAR(5), Id INT) --your table
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
('12:00:00','OK ','1'),('11:59:00','ERR','2'),('11:58:00','OK ','4'),('11:57:00','OK ','3'),
('11:45:00','ERR','4'),('11:20:00','OK ','2'),('11:00:00','ERR','3'),('11:30:00','OK ','5'),
('11:20:00','ERR','1'),('11:10:00','OK ','1'),('11:00:00','ERR','1'),('10:30:00','ERR','5')

DECLARE @ROWER TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Timestmp TIME(1)) 
INSERT INTO @ROWER SELECT Timestmp FROM @table WHERE Comment='OK' ORDER BY Timestmp

DECLARE @TIME TIME(1) = '11:00:00' --your condition

SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN A.Timestmp >=@TIME THEN A.Timestmp ELSE @TIME END     ErrorStart,
        CASE WHEN B.Timestmp > A.Timestmp THEN B.Timestmp ELSE '' END   ErrorEnd,
A.Id  FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id,Timestmp) rowid,* FROM @table WHERE Comment = 'ERR'
) A  LEFT JOIN (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id,Timestmp) rowid,* FROM @table WHERE Comment = 'OK'
) B ON A.rowid = B.rowid
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT A.id,A.Timestmp t1,B.Timestmp t2 FROM @ROWER A 
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT id-1 id, Timestmp FROM @ROWER) B ON A.id=B.id
) C ON A.Timestmp BETWEEN C.t1 AND C.t2 ORDER BY A.Id
```

Hope it helps. :)